# How to navigate with Buttons and BottomNavigationBar Flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, button, navigation

I`m new in Flutter and I have a big problem.
I want to use a BottomNavBar, for switching screens and I want to have in these screens buttons, where i can navigate to another screens. When I´m trying to put my written Code with the Buttons into the onTab, it says that it has a problem with context, which I used to navigate with the Buttons. Can anyone help me?
Thanks for all answers.
Here is my Code

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
 import 'dart:math';

  void main() {
 runApp(MaterialApp(
  title: 'Navigation Basics',
   debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
   home: FirstRoute(),
  ));
   }

class FirstRoute extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
  _FirstRouteState createState() => _FirstRouteState();
}

class _FirstRouteState extends State<FirstRoute> {
 int _currentIndex = 0;
 final tabs = [
   Center(),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
     bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
     currentIndex: _currentIndex,
    items: [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.indigo),
          title: Text(
            "Home",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.indigo),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.indigo),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.settings,
            color: Colors.indigo,
          ),
          title: Text(
            "Settings",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.indigo),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.indigo),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.folder, color: Colors.indigo),
          title: Text(
            "Saved",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.indigo),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.indigo),
    ],
    onTap: (index) {
      setState(() {
        _currentIndex = index;
      });
    },
  ),
  appBar: PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(35.0),
    child: AppBar(
      title: Text(
        "BeGentle",
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
    ),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: new ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.indigo,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(1.0),
                spreadRadius: 5,
                blurRadius: 10,
                // changes position of shadow
              ),
            ],
          ),
          height: 120.0,
          width: 400.0,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => 
SecondRoute1()),
              );
            },
            child: Text(
              "Öffentlichkeit",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 32.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.indigo,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(1.0),
                spreadRadius: 5,
                blurRadius: 10,
                // changes position of shadow
              ),
            ],
          ),
          height: 120.0,
          width: 400.0,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => 
SecondRoute2()),
              );
            },
            child: Text(
              "Gesprächsthemen",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 32.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.indigo,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(1.0),
                spreadRadius: 5,
                blurRadius: 10,
                // changes position of shadow
              ),
            ],
          ),
          height: 120.0,
          width: 400.0,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => 
SecondRoute3()),
              );
            },
            child: Text(
              "Essen",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 34.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.indigo,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(1.0),
                spreadRadius: 5,
                blurRadius: 10,
                // changes position of shadow
              ),
            ],
          ),
          height: 120.0,
          width: 400.0,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => 
 SecondRoute4()),
              );
            },
            child: Text(
              "Treffen",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 32.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.indigo,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(1.0),
                spreadRadius: 5,
                blurRadius: 10,
                // changes position of shadow
              ),
            ],
          ),
          height: 120.0,
          width: 400.0,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => 
SecondRoute5()),
              );
            },
            child: Text(
              "Social Interacting",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 32.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
       ),
     );
    }
}
```

Comment: The linked file is 5941 lines long... that is too long for anyone to read. Can you only show the most relevant parts?

Comment: Hi, even though your question includes example code (in an external link), I'd recommend reducing it to a minimum reproducible example.  I'm saying this because the link you provided has 5,941 lines of code, which makes it very overwhelming to anyone trying to help.

Comment: Oh yes sorry I will fix it

Comment: I have fixed it is it better now?

Answer (score 0):

just use IndexedStack widget as the body of Your BottomNavBar Screen and use any of the packages from this link for the bottom navigation bar
https://pub.dev/packages?q=Bottom+Navigation+Bar
and paste your screen names inside IndexedStack and update your index variable with the onPressed on the navbar.